# Flutter Package URI doesn't exist inside package's test

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

Inside the **Flutter project** directory, I created a package with the following command :

```
 flutter create --template=package emoji_support
```

After it completes creating the package and **completes flutter get**.

But..

Files inisde `package's /test directory` can't find files inside `package's /lib directory` :

`import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';` is resolved ✅

But...

`import 'package:emoji_support/emoji_support.dart';` is not resolved ❌

[image]

File structure

[image]

What error am I making here?

Comment: I'm speculating but that import package works in the root project package:hundreddaysofflutter/...,  So maybe you need to add the dependency of the inner package to your pubspec first (like a normal package) with the path: ./emoji_support

Comment: No it doesn't in root either in my case. It doesn't work even inside the package's own test directory which is standalone and self-sufficient project

Comment: Have you tested with a relative import "../lib/emoji_support.dart";

Comment: Yeah I did test but didn't work

Comment: i tried my first comment and it worked, did you add the package to the pubspec.yaml of the hundereddaysofflutter? not the one inside emoji_support

Comment: No I didn't as It wasn't being found within its own package. Does the package depend on another project which imports it to function properly? I didn't understand it

Comment: check my answer, for what I understand import 'package/..whatever/..'; checks in the scope of the project, in this case your project is hundreddaysofflutter and your package is inside that project, that's why it doesnt detect it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a package inside my project `flutter_example_file_picker` with `flutter create --template=package emoji_support`

[image]

Then in the pubspec.yaml of the project (not the one inside the plugin) `flutter_example_file_picker > pubspec.yaml` I added to the dependenceis the package

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  emoji_support:
    path: ./emoji_support
```

and the problem resolved, I could run the test with no problem, also tried with a relative path without adding it to the dependencies and worked too

[image]

**UPDATE**

I think I undestand how to fix it without adding it to the pubspec, when creating a plugin inside a project, the flutter plugin of AndroidStudio (or VS) is still working in the main route (check the terminal dir and it will be C:/.../Workspace_Android\hundreddaysofflutter> so it doesnt detect the inner plugin) and doesn't update to detect the new folder. Even if it's red and says it cannot detect the URI.

You can ignore it and try to run the test and see if it detects the inner dart_tool with package_config.json, then it will run succesfully and the problem will dissapear. The second option is to move to the folder where the plugin is (in the terminal `cd my_plugin_name_folder` or just file open and open the plugin).

Run `flutter get pub` (it does it automatically when creting the first time a project but sometimes when you create one inside another it doesnt do it) to run for the first time the package and create the package_config.json inside dart_tool (the dart_tool of the plugin), at the end of the file you can see the name and rootUri of the package, now you can use it in your test nad it should detect it correctly. Sometimes it's generated but it seems it doesn't update correctly and the IDE doesn't know even if it's there.

Comment: This is strange but It compiles, Why does the package depend on the project/app instead of the other way? You have any idea?

Comment: check my update, I think I found the problem and a way around, it's more of a problem when the IDE doesn't run or detect the pub of the plugin the first time

Comment: Sounds reasonable, will check it out

Answer (score 0):

This is just a problem that occurs , when you are adding new sub_directories in vsCode.
just a simple exist and re-open will fix the issue.
tell me if that fix it.

Comment: didn't help this time